# Gitlab notification for tag's event

Tags: gitlab, notifications

Our team needs to get notification only about the events on tag's pipelines (no need for any other push notifications) by mail, rocketchat (do not ask why:)

We use semantic-release utility to create new tag and trigger pipeline (with project access token/or PAT for techuser).
But if any job failure accures there is no notification.

Using techuser (and its PAT) partially solve this problem by adding notification email to it.
Integration "pipeline status emails" does not work for (protected) tags.
Project webhook allows to push notifications for tags. But there is no posibility to turn on only job's/pipeline's events that occures only for tag's pipeline.

As I think there is only way to do so is to add bash scripted notifyer to after_script section to all jobs for tag's pipeline.

I'd be grateful for any ideas.